# Timed message with jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am referring to question Nr. 18650494 ('Disappear the alert box with time base') and to the solution provided by Deepak Sharma, which works well (code hereafter).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script>
function customAlert(msg,duration)
{
 var styler = document.createElement("div");
  styler.setAttribute("style","border: solid 5px Red;width:auto;height:auto;top:50%;left:40%;background-color:#444;color:Silver");
 styler.innerHTML = "<h1>"+msg+"</h1>";
 setTimeout(function()
 {
   styler.parentNode.removeChild(styler);
 },duration);
 document.body.appendChild(styler);
}
  function caller()
  {
    customAlert("This custom alert box will be closed in 2 seconds","2000");
  }
  </script>
  </head>
<body onload="caller()">

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to implement it while a jQuery dialog is up, but then the message displays in the background of the dialog. This stems, I should think, from styler being appended to document.body.

**How do I display this message (same code, basically) in the *foreground* of a jQuery dialog?**

Addendum: as to Pilatus' question:

I have used jQuery and implemented jQuery dialogs regularly. I suspect things could be straightened by appending the element to the right parent, i.e. the jQuery dialog, but I am not able to locate $('#myDialog').dialog…  in the DOM and name it.  I maybe wrong too… Still I need bring the "custom alert' in the foreground.

Comment: Did you actually try to implement a jQuery dialog?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a question number referenced in a question before

Comment: @chiliNUT. It's high time you saw one. In other words I am not sure where you are driving at: my question is clearly stated, Deepak Sharma's code stately quoted (although not subject to copyright!) and, altogether, I have tried to make it as explicit as possible so that Pilatus appears to have understood it, while I have edited it ('Addendum') for more sharpness — to the best of my ability. The id of a question is in my view an efficient means of reference:  type in the URL field of your browser 'stackoverflow.com/questions/' immediately followed by the number and check how efficient it is.

Comment: @Ectoplasm my reference was not implying anything my friend, I just thought it was a novel way of referencing another question. The comment had no negative connotation intended. Fyi, it is just more common to include an actual link in your question, rather than the question number.